# Application of Unsigned right shift and bit masking

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

When I went through numerous websites before posting this question on bit masking all i understood was it's used to toggle switch between 1's and 0's and usually used in pixel based graphic project. Now as a beginner really didn't understand why do we toggle the switch and how it is used in graphics.. **Also why do we use bit masking to extract the bits**??

Comment: Why is this tagged with three different languages, when you only seem to be talking about Java? Rules for sign-extension and bit-shifting cannot be expected to be the same across a random set of programming languages ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in the JLS. Section 5.6.2:

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> - Otherwise,if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
> - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

The last point is of interest. This means that both `b` is converted to `int` *before* the shift operation is carried out.

Thus, `b`, which used to be `0xF1`, is promoted to `0xFFFF FFF1`.

Then the shift is performed:

```
0xFFFF FFF1 >>> 4 == 0x0FFF FFFF
```

Then casted to `byte`:

```
(byte) 0x0FFF FFFF == 0xFF
```

And you get `b == -1`.

---

`e` is 15 because of the mask.

First, `b` is promoted from `0xF1` to `0xFFFF FFF1`.

Then it is `AND`ed with `0xFF`:

```
0xFFFF FFF1 & 0x0000 00FF == 0x0000 00F1
```

Then it is shifted right 4 bits:

```
0x0000 00F1 >> 4 == 0x0000 000F
```

Then it is casted to `byte`:

```
(byte) 0x0000 000F == 0x0F
```

And you get `e == 15`

Edit: Didn't hit "F" enough times, ended up with 16-bit `int`s... Hopefully fixed, thanks @Stefan!

Comment: Even though the point stays the same, ain't Java int's also 32-bit, not 16?

Comment: @Stefan Right, gotta tack on more `F`s... Thanks for the catch!